# Veracrypt Dual Boot Linux and Windows?

Tags: encryption, linux, windows-10, veracrypt

I know that Veracrypt only supports Dual Encryption on Windows.

I am searching for a workaround: I am trying to dual boot Windows and Linux with encryption.

Answer (score 2):

Install Windows on a SSD/HDD. Encrypt it completely.
Disconnect it.

Install Linux on another SSD/HDD. Encrypt it completely.
Reconnect the Windows one also.

Use BIOS/UEFI quick boot select key to select which one you want to boot into.

This way, both systems are completely encrypted and do not interfere with each other.

Comment: - how to encrypt the Linux one Vera crypt or LUKS? -Is it possible to do that with one SSD?

Comment: You can use VC on Windows and LUKS on Linux, not a problem.